# CSS of a asp textbox control

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, stylesheet

I have a ASP text box control. When the user focuses on text box, i want to change the background color of the text box from gray to white.

here is the css file, but its not changing the color after focusing on the text box.

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text-javascript">
     function DoFocus(txt) 
     {
         txt.className = 'focus';
     }    
   </script>
```

Textbox

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"
        CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="50" Width="188px" onfocus="DoFocus(this)">
```

CSS

```
input.textbox, select, textarea
{
  font-family    :  verdana, arial, snas-serif;
  font-size      :  11px;
  color          :  #000000;

  padding        :  3px;
  background     :  #f0f0f0;
  border-left    :  solid 1px #c1c1c1;
  border-top     :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  border-right   :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  border-bottom  :  solid 1px #6f6f6f;
}

input.textbox:focus, input.input_text_focus
{
    border-color:#646464;
    background-color:#ffcf03;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** I saw you updated your post, so to clarify: ASP creates an `input` HTML element (correct me if I'm wrong) and you can always style this via the `:focus` selector in CSS, no need for Javascript, but also add `input.textbox:active` to catch some buggy IE...

```
input.textbox:focus, input.textbox:active {
   /* everything you put here will be aplied to ANY focused input element */
}
```

---

Judging from your pasted code, instead of

```
.input_text:focus, input.input_text_focus {
    border-color:#646464;
    background-color:#ffffc0;
}
```

use

```
input.textbox:focus, input.input_text_focus {
   ...
}
```

Or why do you suddenly use the class `input_text` when you have `input.textbox` in the firsthand? Your two selectors don't match...

Comment: just one thing i wanted to ask, why does highlighting work when i add the style manually to the aspx page, and not the stylesheet?

Comment: This might be that there are other styles comming from some other stylesheet... try using `background-color: #ffffc0 !important;`...

Comment: well i have just referenced just 1 stylesheet in my page. i only am using 1 in my project

Comment: I have not worked with ASP yet, so I can't tell you whether it does generate some default stylesheet by itself. Another thing to consider is that browsers have default stylesheets, try including a `reset.css` (google it ;). Inline styles (entering them directly in your page) work, because they are more "specific", you can also try adding more selectors like `#content form input.textbox:focus` if your form is contained in a div with id `content`...

Answer (score 2):

Here an approach with the use separated CSS classes specified via javascript:

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.FocusedStyle
    {
        background-color:#ffffc0;
        border-color:#646464;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnBlur(textBox) {
        textBox.className = '';
    }
    function OnFocus(textBox) {
        textBox.className += ' FocusedStyle';
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" onblur="OnBlur(this);" onfocus="OnFocus(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  TEXTAREA, INPUT[type="text"]
  {
    font-family    :  tahoma, arial, snas-serif;
    font-size      :  11px;
    color          :  #000000;

    padding        :  3px;
    background     :  #EEEfff;
    border-left    :  solid 1px #c1c1c1;
    border-top     :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    border-right   :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    border-bottom  :  solid 1px #6f6f6f;
  }

  INPUT[type="text"]:focus, INPUT[type="text"]:active 
  {
      border-color:#646464;
      background-color:#ffcf03;
  }
```

Comment: Good answer for all I know, but in general you should try and leave a comment explaining what you did ... code-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Old i know but this is far better than using JavaScript to set focus. Using Pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it by just using css. you have to use javascript as well.  For example:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="myTextbox" onfocus="DoFocus(this)" onblur="DoBlur(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

the javascript section:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function DoFocus(txt) 
  {
      txt.className = 'focus';
  }          

  function DoBlur(txt) 
  {
      txt.className = 'unfocus';
  }
</script>
```

and the css:

```
input.textbox, select, textarea, unfocus
{
 font-family    :  verdana, arial, snas-serif;
 font-size      :  11px;
 color          :  #000000;
 padding        :  3px;
 background     :  #f0f0f0;
 border-left    :  solid 1px #c1c1c1;
 border-top     :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
 border-right   :  solid 1px #cfcfcf;
border-bottom  :  solid 1px #6f6f6f;
}

.focus
{
    border-color:#646464;
    background-color:#ffffc0;
}
```

You can find some good examples at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/inputBgOnFocus.aspx
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/09/change-form-input-textbox-style-focus-jquery.html
http://forums.asp.net/t/1134964.aspx/1

Comment: i have done what u said but it doesnt work...i have edited the code in the main post....

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to change the css class name. Updated the answer, lookl at the CSS class name. it should be `focus`

Comment: Also type should be `text/javascript`. my bad!