# Why can't I apply css on textboxes in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox

I have a problem with applying css on textboxes in asp.net!!

Here is my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="128px" 
    BackColor="#CCCCCC"></asp:TextBox>
```

As u see I added CssClass to the textbox. Here is the css i am using

```
.textbox
{ 
   background-color: Red;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

What is the problem? I googled, but can't find the answer!!

Comment: use input.textbox or input[type="text"]

Comment: I am adding css to: Documentation.css.

Comment: Also not to forget to mentione, I am using dotnetnuke...

Comment: try to change the class name

Comment: @Anna.P, i used that code... didn't work either :(

Comment: @Sora o tried, but nothign :(

Comment: i can't see anything wrong with your code are u puting this code in the same page or in a separated css stylesheet and you r calling it ? and if you are calling the separated stylesheet make sure you give it the right path

Comment: its working fine for me...http://jsfiddle.net/kHSNC/6/

Comment: You specified inline BackColor property. it has more precedent over css class.

Comment: @Anna.P: Width, Height and BackColor are ASP.NET properties. you can'y use them in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you using IE. if yes then please check number of css file is not more than 30. if file is more then 30 then file will not include in page.

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ - read this, it explains what's going on here.

Answer (score 6):

Remove your `BackColor="#CCCCCC"` attribute.
Asp.net renders this as in inline css style on the element.

Inline styles have more precedence  in CSS over css classes.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" 
     Height="22px" Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>

.textbox
{ 
   background-color: Red;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input.textbox
{ 
 background-color: Red;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Please use input.textbox instead pf only .textbox.

Comment: Please refer to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610409/css-of-a-asp-textbox-control

Answer (score 0):

It's a css style rule precedence problem. BackColor property that you have specified translates to `style="background-color:#cccccc"`. so this color is applied instead of red (css class). and also DonNetNuke css rules may override your rules.

So, use more specific rules (like the one @Gayatri mentioned in his answer). Use browsers 'Inspect element' future to determine witch style is overriding others.

Answer (score -1):

try to add important

```
input[type=”text”]
 { 
 background-color: Red!important;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: No, never use `!important`.